# Setting Subnet Mask with DHCPD Conf

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, dhcp, jessie-lite

I'm using Raspberry PI 3 with Raspbian Jessie to make an industrial datalogger product.
For obvious reasons I need to tell the Rasp to use a static IP configuration, in order to make it work in other networks. After googling I found out that the proper way to achieve that was to alter the **dhcpdcd.conf** file (/etc/dhcpcd.conf) adding the following lines:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.168.207
static routers=192.168.168.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.168.254
```

When I know (or at least I think so) I'm giving the dhcp client the static **IP**, **Default Gateway** (routers) and **DNS Address**, which is good. Everything is fine and the Pi actually uses those information.

**The problem is the subnet mask**. So far, I couldn't figure out how to set it properly. Setting this info is crucial (I guess), since this device will work in different networks, including different subnetworks. What I would like to configure is a simple subnet mask, (such as 255.255.0.0, or even more subnetted).

I'm a missing something ? Maybe something TCP\IP related. Is subnet mask an optional parameter when configuring a device nowadays?

Comment: from what I understand, your last octet `192.168.168.x` addresses tend to change. This should imply that your subnet mask is `255.255.255.0` because you need to mask the first three octets of the IPv4 address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem to set a Subnet Mask 255.255.254.0 for static IP 192.168.161.154 in /etc/dhcpcd.conf. How I address this is by adding ***/23*** at the end of the static IP address,

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.161.154/23
```

For the above discussed issue, it can be addressed by adding ***/16***, as specified below.

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.168.207/16
static routers=192.168.168.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.168.254
```

For more reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think "For obvious reasons I need to tell the Rasp to use a static IP", but putting this aside I don't know why you think this is the correct way to set `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (it certainly didn't come from the `man` page) - `dhcpcd` uses [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) format.

To add to the above the value you are using for `routers=` seems improbable.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for an example and suggested methods for determining the correct values.

Comment: Regarding static configurations: static IP address is a must and a standard in every industrial enviroment, at least in my country. You must be able to connect to a device with always the same configuration (including IP and Port) in order to automate its use